# Resistance Multiplier

Tags: operational-amplifier, multiplier

The circuit below is a resistance multiplier but I am having trouble deriving the effective input resistance, which should be a multiple of \$R_b\$.

The answer should be something like $$R_{\text{in}} = (1+R_3/R_1)R_b$$

Any thoughts on how to derive this?

[image: Resistance Multiplier]

Comment: To have an \$R_{in}\$ you need to define a \$V_{in}\$ and \$I_{in}\$.

Comment: Use a Current source Ip to determine Vp as a function of all R's then you will know.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I would solve this is to divide it into two parts, the photodiode circuit and the resistor divider.

A photo diode circuit (if R1 and R3 were removed would be:
\$ V_{out} = R_b *(-i_p) \$

A voltage divider from V2 to Vout is:
\$ V_2 = V_{out}*\frac{R_3}{R_1+R_3} \$

rearrange:

\$ V_{out} = V_2*\frac{R_1+R_3}{R_3} \$

Then I just take a shortcut and consider the voltage divider to be a "gain" in the feedback path and substitute

\$ V_{out} = R_b i_p \frac{R_1+R_3}{R_3} =  R_b i_p (1+\frac{R_1}{R_3})\$

You could also use node voltage but I'm too lazy, if you do, the V- terminal would be zero (for an op amp in feedback), then you consider the only path of \$i_p \$ to go through \$ R_p\$ then solve V_2 and Vout and end up with only a Vout equation

Edit:

Soruce transformation, since there is no current going to V- the equation for the node V2 would be this:

\$ V_{2} = R_b -i_p \$

Why? (although I drew the current in the wrong direction, but you get the drift)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTsZ0C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

so 
\$ V_{2} = -R_b i_p \$

\$ V_2 = V_{out}*\frac{R_3}{R_1+R_3} \$

Comment: Can you explain why you can apply the voltage divider from V2 to Vout while disregarding the current through the photodiode? I think this is what I am having trouble with.

Comment: I  had a closer look at your solution I believe your voltage divider is reversed. It should be \$V_2 = V_{out} * \frac{R_3}{R_1+R_3}\$. 
Also what was your reasoning for removing R1 and R3? Using nodal analysis I seem to get \$V_{out} = i_p(R_1 +\frac{R_1}{R_3}R_b+R_b)\$

Comment: I did get something backwards I put \$ V_2 = V_{out}*\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_3} \$ when it is really \$ V_2 = V_{out}*\frac{R_3}{R_1+R_3} \$